# Error within render when the state is null?

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple component which initializes the state in constructor and function

```
this.remove = this.remove.bind(this)
this.state = {
  lalo: this.Service.getObjects() //Array
};
```

In render method I try to validate if lalo is null

```
render() {
    if (this.state.lalo !== null) {
      return (
        //Load if state has items, also pass the function to a child component which can remove items from this state.
      );
    } else {
      return <p>None.</p>;
    }
  }
```

Also a method which remove items from the state

```
remove = id => {
    this.setState(state => {
      var lalo = state.lalo.filter(item => item.id !== id);
      return {
        lalo
      };
    });
};
```

The problem I am having is that when I delete all the items from the state, the render method throws an error of undefined and it seems that it doesn't render the 'else' part but the true condition.

Comment: try this:  `return (
   {{ this.state.lalo &&  // your child component or function}}
   
  );`

Comment: did you check?
`if (this.state.lalo !== null && this.state.lalo !== undefined) {
  return (
    //Load if state has items, also pass the function to a child component which can remove items from this state.
  );
}`

Comment: check this `this.state.lalo !== null && this.state.lalo.length>0`

Comment: He doesn't ever set it to null, so `this.state.lalo.length > 0` should actually suffice

Comment: (2) [firstObject, secondObject]
[firstObject] --> I deleted one from the state array.
[] --> Empty
[] --> Empty, I don't understand why the console logs two empty.

PD: Patrick Hund, you got it, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Is there a reason that `this.state.lalo.length > 0` works but this is not --> `this.state.lalo !== []` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your condition

> this.state.lalo !== null

as you are removing all elements then this.state.lalo = [] which is not equal to null, so above condition becomes true and it will try to render your child component instead of text None.

You can update your condition to

> if (this.state.lalo && this.state.lalo.length > 0) {...

or handle empty array in your child component.